# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer looks to be iPhone 4 size

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm using this code to display a camera in my iOS 9, Swift app:

Properties:

```
@IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!

var session: AVCaptureSession!
var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
var output: AVCaptureStillImageOutput!
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
```

Delegate methods:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setupSession()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    // Experimental / debugging
    view.layoutSubviews()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // Experimental / debugging
    previewLayer!.frame = previewView.bounds
}
```

Camera methods:

```
func setupSession() {
    session = AVCaptureSession()
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    let camera = frontCamera()

    do { input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera) } catch { return }

    output = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    output.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]

    guard session.canAddInput(input) && session.canAddOutput(output) else { return }

    session.addInput(input)
    session.addOutput(output)

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
    previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
    previewLayer!.frame = previewView.bounds
    previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = .Portrait

    previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

    session.startRunning()
}

func frontCamera() -> AVCaptureDevice! {
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    for device in devices {
        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front) {
            return device as! AVCaptureDevice
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

**However**, the camera is displayed like this:

[image]

And it appears to be equivalent to the display size of an iPhone 4.

How can I solve this? I've tried setting the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, but I can't get it sized properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to override the layoutSubivews or viewDidLayoutSUbviews method.

1. Make sure the `previewView` is constrainted to `superview` (If you are using autolayout)
2. Make sure the bounds of `previewLayer` is same as `previewView` `bounds`. Don't get confused while giving the frame value to bounds or bound value to frame.
3. set the video gravity of the preview layer to `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`.

4.You can position the `previewLayer` and make it center to the `previewView` . Use position property of `previewLayer` and set it to the center of `previewView`.

5. call the `setupSession()` either in `viewDidAppear`/`viewWillAppear`

Comment: Number 3 solved it, apparently the last four characters "Fill" did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have launch images assigned for the all supported devices. If not, then iOS will default to that size no matter what you do.